# Jquery Ajax not working on IE

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I got very strange bug on IE. I used the code below to make a ajax request to get data from database and create drop down option `<option>` with that data. The thing is on IE the data didn't appear properly, it's only showing first character of data, but on other browser the data are showing correctly. I tried printing out the data as well, data are correct. 
So I suspected either of my Jquery selection or append is wrong and tried appending outside the ajax call with some junk data and data are showing correctly but then again I put that code inside the ajax and its not showing again... I really out of clue now.. Can you guy plz help me with this? I have tested with FF, Chrome and safari they all working fine...

```
$.ajax({

    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/rewards/getdiscounttype/",
    data: { esid: estore_id }

}).done(function( data ) {

    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    jQuery.each(obj, function (i, app) {

        //alert(i+app['discount_type']);
        var sel = $('select[name=discount_type'+id+']');
        sel.append('<option value="'+app['id']+'">'+app['discount_type']+'</option>');

    });

});
```

Comment: could you post an example of your json? and what is the 'id' variable in `var sel = $('select[name=discount_type'+id+']');`

Comment: umm id was used to target each drop down in a form field. It was actually passed in as parameter on the very top function. And here is my json [{"id":19,"discount_type":"20%"},{"id":51,"discount_type":"test"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now with JavaScript!

```
$.ajax({

cache: false,
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/rewards/getdiscounttype/",
data: { esid: estore_id } 

}).done(function( data ) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    /* clearing options with JS since jQuery cleare the select in the DOM but enter code   herenot on screen. */
    $('select[name=discount_type'+id+']')[0].options.length = 0;
    $('select[name=discount_type'+id+']').children().remove().end().append('');

    jQuery.each(obj, function (i, app) {
       var sel = $('select[name=discount_type'+id+']');
       sel.append('<option value="'+app.id+'">'+app.discount_type+'</option>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({

    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/rewards/getdiscounttype/",
    data: { esid: estore_id },
    datatype: "json",
    succes: function(jsonData){
        $.each(jsonData,function(i,app){
            var sel = $('select[name=discount_type'+i+']');
            sel.append('<option value="'+app.id.+'">'+app.discount_type.+'</option>');
        });
    },
    error: function(e){

    }

})
```

Try this, and I think its better to treat JSON as objects like   app.id in stead of app['id']. Haven't had much time to do some testing, Ive you would give me the json you receive I can test.